# npm install stuck on node lib/install.js

Tags: node.js, zurb-foundation

I'm running in an issue trying to install foundations email framework. After running the command `foundation new --framework emails` the installations get stuck at the point, where the terminal output says `node lib/install.js`.

I've tried to cancel the installation, deleting the node_modules folder and rerun the installation process via `npm install` => same problem.

Cancalling the process and going on with the next step (`npm start`), results in an error, saying that node-sass could not be find.

I'm running an Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS via VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host-system. The guest system has 2048MB working storage.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to cancel the operation with `CTRL + C` in Windows 10 Power Shell.

Then I ran `npm install gifsicle@3.0.4`

After successful installation of the package, I then ran `npm install` again.
And that completed quickly and successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems there was a problem with the package gifsicle. I cancelled the installation process, went to github and downloaded the [gifsicle-package](https://github.com/imagemin/gifsicle-bin) there. Then I put it in my `node_modules/gifsicle` directory and re-ran `npm install`. 
Now npm start works without any problems.